# Changing updated_at in a Rails record

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a memory based session table containing the following:

```
id

sessnhash

userid

created_at

updated_at
```

The idea is that when a user first logs in a random `sessnhash` is created and passed back so that all further actions have to send that sessionhash for server requests.  These go through a loggedin? method on the application controller which simply checks that a row in the table exists for that sessionhash.

I now want to extend this functionality to keep a tab of the last time any activity happened for that user and I thought one of way of doing this would be to immediately do a save after finding the sessionhash, hoping that this would then update the 'updated_at' attribute.

However Rails is too clever and doesn't update anything as in reality nothing has been updated.

Is there any way of forcing Rails to update the updated_at attribute without having to make any data changes to any of the other attributes?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've just learnt that I need to do.

```
sessn.touch
```

which will update the `updated_at` attribute.

It's all in here: [`touch`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch).